# pytorch 0.4.1 - ‘LSTM’ object has no attribute ‘weight_ih_l’

Tags: lstm, pytorch

Simple question. I’d like to see the initialized parameter of LSTM. How do I see it?
Do I need to always put lstm in the model to see the params?

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
​
torch.manual_seed(1)
torch.__version__
​
lstm = nn.LSTM(3, 3)  
​
lstm.weight_ih_l
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         9 lstm = nn.LSTM(3, 3)
>        10 
>   ---> 11 lstm.weight_ih_l
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch0.41/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py
>   in **getattr**(self, name)
>       516                 return modules[name]
>       517         raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
>   --> 518             type(self).**name**, name))
>       519 
>       520     def **setattr**(self, name, value):
>
> AttributeError: 'LSTM' object has no attribute 'weight_ih_l'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nn.LSTM` is implemented with `nn.RNNBase` which puts all the parameters inside the OrderedDict: _parameters. So to 'see' the initialized parameters, you can simply do:

```
import torch
torch.manual_seed(1)

import torch.nn as nn

lstm = nn.LSTM(3, 3)

print(lstm._parameters['weight_ih_l0'])
```

Also, to know what are the keys value in that OrderedDict, you can simply do:
`print(lstm._all_weights)`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically I didn't specify the layer # `'0'`.

`lstm.weight_ih_l0` does the job as well.

Adding to the answer above, you need to specify the layer index of your parameters. If you want to see second layer, `weight_ih_l1`.

Comment: It always helps to open `ipython` and using tab completion to see what options are available and make a guess :P